# JSON to TableView difficulty

Tags: ios, iphone, json, uitableview, swifty-json

I am having difficulty populating a tableview from a json result.  My code is as follows (apologies but it does not seem to want to want to put the first two lines as code :/):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    let teamsArray = json["teams"] as NSArray

    print("Team List : \(teamsArray)")

    for dic in teamsArray
    {
        let teamname = dic["name"] as NSString

        let code = dic["code"] as NSString

        println("Team Name, \(teamname) : Code, \(code)")
    }

    //        self.tableViewObject.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewObject: UITableView!




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return teamsArray.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = teamsArray[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

}

It is complaining twice about "Use of unresolved identifier 'teamsArray' twice.  First at:

return teamsArray.count

and then at:

cell.textLabel!.text = teamsArray[indexPath.row]

Can someone help me link my JSON with my tableview please by helping me resolve the error mentioned above or putting me in the correct direction.

It is worth noting when I use the code on a blank view without any hint of a tableview I get perfect results in the console:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    let teamsArray = json["teams"] as NSArray

    print("Team List : \(teamsArray)")

    for dic in teamsArray
    {
        let teamname = dic["name"] as NSString

        let code = dic["code"] as NSString

        println("Team Name, \(teamname) : Code, \(code)")
    }
```

I am new to stackoverflow and was told my question earlier was not specific enough.  Please let me know if this is still too vague and I will try to improve on it.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: You need to learn about `scope`. You're declaring `teamsArray` in `viewDidLoad`, but you're using it in other methods. By declaring it inside `viewDidLoad`, you're telling your code that you only need it inside `viewDidLoad`. So when you try to reference it in other methods, it doesn't know about it. Think of it this way: if you're hiding in your house, can someone from the street see you? This is what's happening right now. You need to declare it one level higher for it to work.

Comment: I thought that would be the case but when I had it one level higher the code itself would simply not run at all :/

Comment: How were you using it? Try having the following `class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource { var teamsArray : NSArray { override func viewDidLoad() ....`. Then inside `viewDidLoad`, do `self.teamsArray = json["teams"]`. I don't write in swift so it might not be exactly 100% correct, but should be along the right lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this...

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController:   UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableViewObject: UITableView!
 var teamsArray = NSArray()
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()

self.tableViewObject.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

teamsArray = json["teams"] as NSArray

print("Team List : \(teamsArray)")

self.tableViewObject.reloadData()

for dic in teamsArray
{
    let teamname = dic["name"] as NSString

    let code = dic["code"] as NSString

    println("Team Name, \(teamname) : Code, \(code)")
}


}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
return teamsArray.count
}



 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
cell.textLabel!.text = self.teamsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("name") as? NSString


return cell
}
```

Comment: Hello there,  many thanks for the code.  I did copy it in and I get a successful build but it errors when it runs.  I will add the error image to the question to see if it helps.  Maybe I have setup my view controller incorrectly?  If you can offer up a zip of it that would be perfect but I appreciate that is cheeky for me to ask. Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Apologies but I am unable to upload an image until I have 10 reputation points. Sorry.

Comment: What error do you get?Because i have implemented same code in my xcode and works perfect.

Comment: Ignore me, it was my input file causing the issue not your code :)  Many thanks for your help.